# Masked JFormattedTextField prevent deleting slash char

Tags: java, swing, date-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I'm creating a frame with a JFormattedTextField masked with MaskFormatter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(df);
    tf.setColumns(20);
    panel.add(tf);
    try {
        MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##-##-####");
        dateMask.install(tf);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MaskFormatterTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    frame.add(new JButton(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

OK. It's alright, but when i delete (with keyboard key) the text i write in the field too delete slashes. Are there any mode to prevent it? I want delete the text but the slashes not, like:

Writing date:

```
"12-12-1212"
```

After delete:

```
"  -  -    "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you delete the text? Are you using `setText("")`? You should not do that. Use `setValue(null)` instead.
If that is not your problem, please elaborate on what you are doing, and what is happening instead.

edit: Try out this code and see if the problem persists.

```
public class Tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(df);
    tf.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);
    tf.setColumns(20);
    panel.add(tf);
    try {
      MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##-##-####");
      dateMask.install(tf);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
    }

    frame.add(new JButton(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}´
```

edit2:
try adding
    tf.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);
see the [JavDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) for further reading.

Comment: This does work in your example, if I try it out. The `-` character stays in place. Usually the JFormattedTextField behaves this way, if you give it an invalid text, it kind of breaks this way. Can you post all of your code?

Comment: What is the button supposed to do? Are you pressing it? If I do that, it breaks the field. Though currently not sure why.

Comment: For now nothing, is only a test, in the future only prints the jtextfield in screen. When i press it without press "tab" the field deletes at all, when i press "tab" the correct date persists and when i delete with the keyboard it deletes all the chars in the field (slashes included)

Comment: Thanks! it's right! I throught that setFocusLostBehavior only works when the focus is changed, not when delete the text. Thanks! Accepted ;-)